# List of Happy Numbers in scala

Tags: programming-challenge, interview-questions, functional-programming, scala, memoization

Definition of [Happy numbers taken from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number).

> A happy number is defined by the following process: Starting with any positive integer, replace the number by the sum of the squares of its digits in base-ten, and repeat the process until the number either equals 1 (where it will stay), or it loops endlessly in a cycle that does not include 1. Those numbers for which this process ends in 1 are happy numbers, while those that do not end in 1 are unhappy numbers (or sad numbers)
>
> Example: 19 is happy, as the associated sequence is
>
> 1*1 + 9*9 = 82,
>   8*8 + 2*2 = 68,
>   6*6 + 8*8 = 100,
>   1*1 + 0*0 + 0*0 = 1.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Set

object HappyNumber extends App {

  def findSquareSum(n: Int): Int =
    n.toString.foldLeft(0) { (product, num) => product + num.asDigit * num.asDigit }

  val visited = Set[Int]()

  def isHappyNumber(n: Int): Boolean = {
    n match {
      case 1 => true
      case _  =>
        if (visited contains n) false
        else {
          visited += n
          if (isHappyNumber(findSquareSum(n))) { visited -= n; true} else false
        }
    }
  }

  (1 to 247) foreach { num => if(isHappyNumber(num)) println(num) }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `findSquareSum()`, what you've labelled as `product` is actually a sum. So that's a little confusing. The digits squared is a product but adding them together is a running sum.

I like to avoid transitions to/from `String` representation whenever possible, but that's mostly a style thing.

If you make the `visited` set a passed parameter to the `isHappyNumber()` method, you can

1. keep it immutable
2. avoid emptying it between runs
3. make the method tail recursive, which will be faster and more memory efficient

.

```
def isHappyNumber(n: Int, seen: Set[Int] = Set()): Boolean =
  if (n == 1) true
  else if (seen(n)) false
  else isHappyNumber(findSquareSum(n), seen+n)
```

Here I've given the `Set`, now called `seen`, a default value (empty) so it doesn't have to be specified when invoked.

```
(1 to 247).filter(isHappyNumber(_)).foreach(println)
```

---

**UPDATE**

Ah, I see that I've missed the point and purpose of your `visited` set, which is to cache unhappy numbers in order to reduce the recursive iterations in future calculations. Not a bad idea, but the obvious next question is: Why not cache all the `isHappyNumber()` results? You'll have quick lookups on all calculations and you won't have to back-out the happy number results.

```
//memoize a function of arity-2 but only cache the 1st parameter
//
def memo[A,B,R](f :(A,B)=>R): (A,B)=>R = {
  val cache = new collection.mutable.WeakHashMap[A,R]
  (a:A,b:B) => cache.getOrElseUpdate(a,f(a,b))
}

//isHappyNumer() is now a memoized function
// for quick lookup of both happy and unhappy numbers
//
val isHappyNumber :(Int, Set[Int]) => Boolean = memo { (n, seen) =>
  if (n == 1) true
  else if (seen(n)) false
  else isHappyNumber(findSquareSum(n), seen + n)
}

(1 to 24).filter(isHappyNumber(_,Set())).foreach(println)
```

You'll note that the scope (visibility) of the mutable hash map is kept quite small and local.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I am not emptying the set between runs, but just removing a HappyNumber from it. That makes this algorithm remember the previously  explored "sad numbers" and makes it fast.

If I pass an empty set for every number I will endup computing the set over and over again.

Answer (score 4):

Just a nitpick about naming: the "find" in `findSquareSum` is meaningless, and perhaps even misleading, since it's not searching for anything.  Just `squareSum` would be fine.  Even better, call it something like `sumSquaresOfDigits` to be explicit about what the function does.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to cache both `happy` and `unhappy` numbers

```
def squareSum(n: Int): Int = n.toString.map(_.asDigit).map(x => x * x).sum

def happyNum(n: Int, book: Set[Int], happy: Set[Int], unhappy: Set[Int]): List[Set[Int]] = {
  if(n==1 || happy.contains(n)) List(happy ++ book, unhappy)
  else if(book.contains(n) || unhappy.contains(n)) List(happy, unhappy ++ book)
  else happyNum(squareSum(n), book + n, happy, unhappy)
}

def helper(): Set[Int] = {
  var happy, unhappy = Set[Int]()
  for(i <- 1 to 1000){
    val lis: List[Set[Int]] = happyNum(i, Set(), happy, unhappy)
    happy = lis(0)
    unhappy = lis(1)
  }
  happy + 1
}

def solution(): List[Int] = helper.toList

def solution(num: Int): Boolean = helper.contains(num)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Can you explain why your solution is better than the original? Alternative implementations by themselves are not reviews.